# Creating keystore using RSA private key

Tags: java, keystore

Here we are trying to create keystore using Client Private key,during RunTime.
We are facing while loading privateKey into keystore.

**JKS TYPE:**

```
clientKey=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ...-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(clientKey.getBytes()), "*********".toCharArray());

Exception:
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
```

**PKCS12 TYPE:**

```
clientKey=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ...-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(clientKey.getBytes()), "*********".toCharArray());

Exception:
java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:847)
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1915)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: A private key is not a keystone, in any format. Unclear what you're asking, or attempting, or why you ever thought this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `clientKey` has starting and ending headers. You have to remove them and then decode the key and feed it to the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

You can remove the `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` by:

```
clientKey = clientKey.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
clientKey = clientKey.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
```

And then what you are left with is the Base64 encoded format (PEM). If it is not in base64 encoded format you need to identify the type of encoding and decode it. If it is base64 encoded, you can do the below to decode:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(clientKey)); // <-- clientKey here is without the headers.
```